# How to call to_socket_addrs on a collection of addresses?

Tags: collections, rust, iterator

How do I call `to_socket_addrs()` on an array or vector in Rust? The following code does not compile:

```
extern crate ws;
use std::net::ToSocketAddrs;

fn main() {
    let addrs = ["127.0.0.1:8889", "127.0.0.1:0"]
        .iter()
        .flat_map(|a| a.to_socket_addrs());
    ws::listen(addrs, |out| move |msg| out.send(msg));
}
```

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `std::iter::FlatMap<std::slice::Iter<'_, &str>, std::result::Result<std::vec::IntoIter<std::net::SocketAddr>, std::io::Error>, [closure@src/main.rs:7:19: 7:42]>: std::net::ToSocketAddrs` is not satisfied
 --> src/main.rs:8:5
  |
8 |     ws::listen(addrs, |out| move |msg| out.send(msg));
  |     ^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `std::net::ToSocketAddrs` is not implemented for `std::iter::FlatMap<std::slice::Iter<'_, &str>, std::result::Result<std::vec::IntoIter<std::net::SocketAddr>, std::io::Error>, [closure@src/main.rs:7:19: 7:42]>`
  |
  = note: required by `ws::listen`
```

It took me two hours to understand the error because "trait `X` is not implemented for `std::iter::FlatMap`" reads like the problem is caused by `flat_map`, instead of the demands of `ws::listen`.

Comment: @Stargateur clarified question and added the real offending line. The irony is I tried to post a minimal example, but by misunderstanding the error, I left out the offending line. Hopefully this will be useful to others.

Comment: @PetrusTheron the downvotes are here, because you are not giving us the real code to reproduce your problem. Use the [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/) to write the code, that gives us exactly the error you encountered. Then we will be able to help you.

Comment: If you understood the error and think it's worth keeping the question in SO to help other users, please write the solution and explanation in a proper answer, not as an edit of the question. Right now it's messy

Comment: @PetrusTheron please take a look at the edit E_net4 did and try to provide all the crucial information that are now in the question in the future by yourself. It helps us to help you!

Answer (score 2):

[`to_socket_addrs`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/net/trait.ToSocketAddrs.html) returns a `Result` containing an iterator. `Result` itself implements `IntoIterator`, so [`flat_map`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.flat_map) flattens the result, but not the inner iterator, you need to do that in an extra step:

```
use std::net::ToSocketAddrs;

fn main() {
    let addrs = ["127.0.0.1:8889", "127.0.0.1:0"]
        .iter()
        .flat_map(|a| a.to_socket_addrs())
        .flatten()
        .collect::<Vec<_>>();
    println!("addrs = {:?}!", addrs);
}
```

Comment: Might be worth noting that `Result`'s implementation of `IntoIterator` discards the errors. You can take advantage of `Result`'s implementation of `FromIterator` instead to raise the error on `collect` time.